# Can't reach gRPC server exposed by a nginx ingress in kubernetes

Tags: go, nginx, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, grpcurl

I have a gRPC server exposed by an ingress.
Here are the nginx annotations I use :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true" 
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
```

I am able to request it using grpcurl :

```
grpcurl -d '<arg>:<value>' <address>:443 api.Service/Request
```

But when I use a basic golang program :

```
conn,_ := grpcconn.Dial("<address>:443",grpccon.WithInsecure())

api := apiService.NewServiceClient(conn)

res,err := api.Request(<parameters>)

if err!=nil {
    log.Fatalf("Request failed : %v",err)
}

log.Println(res)
```

I get the error :

```
rpc error : code = Unavailable desc = connection closed
```

Comment: If the server is using TLS, then the client will need to as well. `WithInsecure` may be part of your issue.